# Find Gaps in a single date column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

Good Day everyone,

I need your help.

I am trying to detect gaps in a single column of the type Date or DateTime in SQL Server.

Say we have a list of schools and each school has many records and there is a field of uploadDate.

So something like that:
[image]

My outcome would be something like that:
[image]

Thank you all.

Comment: Isn't `2020-01-04` also missing?

Comment: Please don't post images of `text`; it's text, so please post it as `text`.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select name, dateadd(day, 1, upload_date), dateadd(day, -1, next_upload_date)
from (select t.*,
             lead(upload_date) over (partition by name order by upload_date) as next_upload_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_upload_date <> dateadd(day, 1, upload_date);
```